# Creating plane with triangular strips

Tags: qt, opengl, qt5, mesh

I am trying to create a finely triangulated mesh. In the draw function :

```
// Draws triangular strip as only lines
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);

// Create Cloth Mesh
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
glNormal3f(0,0,1);

for(float i = 0.0 ; i < 2.0; i+=.05)
{
    for(float j = -1.0 ; j < 1.0 ; j+=.05)
    {
        glVertex3f(j,1-i+.05,0);

        glVertex3f(j,1-i,0);
    }
}


glEnd();
```

I get the following output :

[image]

which I what I expected.

But if I rotate the scene, I see this on the back side:

[image]

(If its not clear, its feebly lit mesh, but the triangles are not the same as showing up on front.)

Q1. Shouldn't the back side be not visible at all ? I have these flag enabled :

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
```

Q2. Even if the back side shows up, why does it shows these irregular, long triangles and not the same ones as on front ?

P.S. This is the resize function :

```
void MyGLWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
 int side = qMin(width, height);
 glViewport((width - side) / 2, (height - side) / 2, side, side);

 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();

 glOrtho(-2, +2, -2, +2, 1.0, 15.0);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

P.P.S: Yes, I understand this is not modern OpenGL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, this looks like the triangles, that are produced by the triangle-strip to "jump back" to the left side. This happens whenever you start a new row. Basically, they consist of the last-vertices of the previous row and the first vertices of the next row. Backface culling seems to work, but the large triangles are visible from the back because their winding order is exactly opposite to the one of the small triangles.

If you don't want to have them, you either have to reset the triangle-strip at the end of each row, or use another structure (GL_TRIANGLES).